# SQL Server- How to use data in column for DATEADD - datepart

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I want to pass data from a variable/ from table column as the 'datepart' when using DATEADD function. Below is snippet of my code where I'm seeing the error as below.

```
DECLARE @vchstring VARCHAR(20)
SET @vchstring='month'
SELECT DATEADD(@vchstring,1,GETDATE())
```

I get this error:

> Msg 1023, Level 15, State 1, Line 104
>   Invalid parameter 1 specified for dateadd.

This could be a duplicate, but am not able to find any information.

Comment: You can't do that. You need either dynamic sql or you need to add some IF/ELSE statements or a Case statement that checks `vchstring` value.

Comment: It is annoying that they don't allow that argument to be parameterised

Comment: Ya it is annoying that, we cannot parameterize the datepart within the DATEADD function. I'll create a static function with if/else conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  You would either have to use Dynamic SQL or a nested case/IF or even a SELECT

**Example**

```
DECLARE @vchstring VARCHAR(20)
SET @vchstring='month'

Select Value
 From  ( values ('year'  ,DATEADD(YEAR   ,1,GETDATE()) ) 
               ,('month' ,DATEADD(MONTH  ,1,GETDATE()) ) 
               ,('day'   ,DATEADD(DAY    ,1,GETDATE()) ) 
               ,('hour'  ,DATEADD(HOUR   ,1,GETDATE()) ) 
               ,('minute',DATEADD(MINUTE ,1,GETDATE()) ) 
       ) A (inc,value)
 Where inc = @vchstring
```

**Returns**

```
Value
2020-06-05 10:09:29.660
```

Comment: Thanks @John , this seems better than case condition with lesser no of characters.

Comment: @Idea Always happy to help